# Pandas Dataframe str.match and str.contain

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file with

```
{
    "London": "Location A",   
    "Berlin": "Location B"  
}
```

I have another Dataframe with 2 columns

```
Canberra is the capital of Australia            AUS  1
Berlin is the capital of Germany                GER  1
London is the capital of United Kingdom         UK   1
Berlin is also the art capital of Germany       GER  1
There is a direct flight from berlin to london  OTH  1
Interstate train service are halted             OTH  0
```

I am trying to run through the keys of the `json` and select all rows containing the string (exact match) as in current key.

What I have tried until now :

```
temp_df = pd.read_csv(fileName , header=None)
df = (temp_df[temp_df[2] == 1]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

with open(jsonFileName, encoding='utf-8') as jsonFile:
    jsonData = json.load(jsonFile)

for key in jsonData.keys():
    print(key)
    df2 = (df[df[0].str.lower().str.match(r"\b{}\b".format(key), case=False)]).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(df2.head())
```

When I try to use the `contains`

```
 df2 = (df[df[0].str.lower().str.contains(r"\b{}\b".format(key), regex=True, case=False)]).reset_index(drop=True)
 print(df2.head())
```

Expected Output : For key = London

```
London is the capital of United Kingdom         UK   1
There is a direct flight from berlin to london  OTH  1
```

But, its throwing out :Doubled Results

```
London is the capital of United Kingdom         UK   1
London is the capital of United Kingdom         UK   1
There is a direct flight from berlin to london  OTH  1
There is a direct flight from berlin to london  OTH  1
```

Any pointer on this is helpful.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You don't have a return statement, so it makes sense that nothing is being returned. What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @cggarvey, I have updated the post.

Comment: I'm confused. In your original post, you said "I would like to update the json file with new key and List of rows from answer" but your expected output is not json.

Comment: @cggarvey, yes. for now, i'm only printing it to verify. When I use `contains` instead of `match` it works. But, contains cannot do full word match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not entirely clear on what you're looking to do, but it seems like you're looking for a case-insensitive match over a series of strings.

Here's a way to do it with Series.str.contains.

```
with open(jsonFileName, encoding='utf-8') as jsonFile:
    jsonData = json.load(jsonFile)

# convert the series of strings into lower-case
haystack = df[0].str.lower()

for key in jsonData.keys():

    # convert the key to lower-case
    needle = key.lower()

    # create a boolean indexer of any records in the haystack containing the needle
    matches = haystack.str.contains(needle)

    # create a subset of the dataframe with only those rows
    df2 = df[matches]
    print(df2)
```

You could also use Series.apply to do some more customization:

```
    matches = haystack.apply(lambda x: needle in x)
```

Here's the full code with the provided sample data:

```
# setup the sample data objects
jsonData = {
    "Berlin": "Location A",
    "London": "Location B"
}

temp_df = pd.DataFrame([
    {0: 'Canberra is the capital of Australia', 1: 'AUS', 2: 1},
    {0: 'Berlin is the capital of Germany', 1: 'GER', 2: 1},
    {0: 'London is the capital of United Kingdom', 1: 'UK', 2: 1},
    {0: 'Berlin is also the art capital of Germany', 1: 'GER', 2: 1},
    {0: 'There is a direct flight from berlin to london', 1: 'OTH', 2: 1},
    {0: 'Interstate train service are halted', 1: 'OTH', 2: 0}
])

df = (temp_df[temp_df[2] == 1]).reset_index(drop=True)


# convert the series of strings into lower-case
haystack = df[0].str.lower()

for key in jsonData.keys():

    # convert the key to lower-case
    needle = key.lower()

    # create a boolean indexer of any records in the haystack containing the needle
    matches = haystack.str.contains(needle)

    # create a subset of the dataframe with only those rows
    df2 = df[matches]
    print(df2)
```

Output:

```
                                             0    1  2
2         London is the capital of United Kingdom   UK  1
4  There is a direct flight from berlin to london  OTH  1

                                                0    1  2
1                Berlin is the capital of Germany  GER  1
3       Berlin is also the art capital of Germany  GER  1
4  There is a direct flight from berlin to london  OTH  1
```

Comment: Why is `df2` is throwing double results (twice).

Comment: Given the information you've provided in the original post, it doesn't. I've added a complete snippet including code to setup your test dataframe and the json.